# Update column with a where clause in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How to update a column in Pyspark dataframe with a where clause?

This is similar to this SQL operation :

```
   UPDATE table1 SET alpha1= x WHERE alpha2< 6;
```

where alpha1 and alpha2 are columns of the table1.

For Eg : 
I Have a dataframe table1 with values below :

```
table1

alpha1    alpha2
3         7
4         5
5         4
6         8 

dataframe Table1 after update : 

alpha1    alpha2
3         7
x         5
x         4
6         8
```

How to do this in pyspark dataframe?

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for the [when](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.when) function:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([("3",7),("4",5),("5",4),("6",8)],["alpha1", "alpha2"])
df.show()
>>> +------+------+
>>> |alpha1|alpha2|
>>> +------+------+
>>> |     3|     7|
>>> |     4|     5|
>>> |     5|     4|
>>> |     6|     8|
>>> +------+------+

df2 = df.withColumn("alpha1", pyspark.sql.functions.when(df["alpha2"] < 6, "x").otherwise(df["alpha1"]))
df2.show()
>>>+------+------+
>>>|alpha1|alpha2|
>>>+------+------+
>>>|     3|     7|
>>>|     x|     5|
>>>|     x|     4|
>>>|     6|     8|
>>>+------+------+
```

Comment: Will this overwrite the existing column?

Comment: It will create a new dataframe which in which the column is updated. If you want a new column instead just use a different name